# Having trouble getting this scheduled task to run

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have this script that created the scheduled task to reboot machines on a weekly basis. The task is successfully created but won't automatically run at designated time.

```
# Create task action
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument 'Restart-Computer - Force'
# Create a trigger (Thursday at 9:00 AM)
$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek Thursday -At 9:00am
# The user to run the task
$taskUser = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "LOCALSERVICE" -LogonType ServiceAccount
# The name of the scheduled task.
$taskName = "Weekly Reboot"
# Describe the scheduled task.
$description = "Forcibly reboot the computer at 9:00am on Thursday"
# Register the scheduled task
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -Principal     $taskUser -Description $description
$shellObject = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
$notification = $shellObject.Popup("Computer will reboot in 30 minutes",0,"Reboot Notification")`
```

Task deployed successfully and can be seen in Task Scheduler but won't run automatically.

Comment: See this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/create-a-scheduled-task-with-powershell/f45184d5-3523-4c9d-8d7e-a3b072c75464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with another user:

```
-UserId "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```